# Remove fraction from square root

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a method that turns `Sqrt[7/2]` into `Sqrt[14]/2`? I've tried `Simplify` and `PowerExpand`.

Something along the lines of

```
removeFraction[x_] := Sqrt[Numerator[x^2] Denominator[x^2]]/Denominator[x^2]
```

but that doesn't keep the fraction form I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Defer`

```
removeFraction[x_] := Defer@Evaluate[Sqrt[Numerator[x^2] Denominator[x^2]]]/Denominator[x^2]
```

Now we get the desired result:

```
removeFraction[Sqrt[7/2]]
(*Sqrt[14]/2*)
```